# Creating a list from elements in another list, while dividing the elements into subsequent lists in python

Tags: python, list

I'm sure this question has been asked (probably in much more eloquent ways), but I can't find an answer, thus I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I am trying to iterate through a list and add each element that is not a number into another list. However, each time a number is encountered in the original list, I want a new list to be created within the secondary list. For example, if 'a3buysi8byjs' is the input, the output would be: [[a], [b,u,y,s,i], [b,y,j,s]].

I have tried several things, and decided to simplify my code and start from scratch, which led to the following:

```
     for e in S_li: #going through initial list, all elements available
         if e.isdigit() != True: # if it is an integer, create another list within poss 
             poss.extend(e) #if it is a letter add to the same list in poss.
```

*I also left my comments, because maybe that will help clarify my intent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This would work for your string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

data = 'a3buysi8byjs'

if data[-1].isdigit():
    data += "1"

sublist = []
target = []
for i in data:
    if i.isdigit():
        target.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
    else:
        sublist.append(i)


print(target)
```

Would print:

```
[['a'], ['b', 'u', 'y', 's', 'i'], ['b', 'y', 'j', 's']]
```

Alternative using itertools.groupby:

```
[list(k) for i, k in itertools.groupby(data, lambda x: x.isdigit()) if not i]
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing something very similar.                                                I think my mistake was honestly misunderstanding how to use  ".extend"

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should get you what you are looking for:

```
s =  'a3buysi8byjs5'

partial = []
final = []
for c in s:
    if c.isdigit():
        final.append(partial)
        partial = []
    else:
        partial.append(c)

if len(partial) > 0:
    final.append(partial)

print(final)
```

This should print out: [['a'], ['b', 'u', 'y', 's', 'i'], ['b', 'y', 'j', 's']]